# android-query bitmap rotate using BitmapAjaxCallback

Tags: android

I want to show several images, one after another, from the external memory.
They should be rotated properly. So I use this :

```
for(int b=0; b<blocks_count; b++){
.....
BitmapAjaxCallback cb = new BitmapAjaxCallback();
                cb.file(picFile).targetWidth(300).rotate(true);
                aq.id(imgId).image(cb); 

.....
}
```

It rotates, however the same (first) image is displayed on every spot. 
picFile and imgId are new on every loop, so as far as I understand it caches image and can't renew it on the next loop.

I tried to clearCache() and other methods to renew "cb" - nothing works.
Help required. Thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it should be :

```
        int targetW = 400;      
        BitmapAjaxCallback cb = new BitmapAjaxCallback();
        cb.targetWidth(targetW).rotate(true);
        aq.id(imgId).image(new File(picUri.getPath()), false, targetW, cb);
```

Kudos to Chad Mckittrick :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-query/rIttYqGS_So